# Redirect the application to Home screen after screen timeout

Tags: android, security, session-management

I am creating an application with possible high security in it.
i simply want an application to redirect to its home screen as soon as the screen time runs out.. or after 1 minute when users stop accessing.
Thanks

Comment: use new Handler().postDelay(new Runnable(),delaytime)

Comment: Thanks for replying but..i don't want application to be redirect after exact 1 minute.. i want application to redirect after some time after user stop accessing it.. just like screen timeout in android

Comment: use Thread for it.

Comment: can you provide the required code for it.?

Comment: I have post my answer code.Please tell me it is working or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int counter=0;

boolean isStart=true;

private void start(){

Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {

    while (isStart){

        try {

            Thread.sleep(100);

            counter++;

            if(counter>=10){//for one minute

                //your code

                isStart=false;

            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}

});

t.start();

}
```

set counter zero when user access.

Comment: the problem is how to reset the counter to 0

Comment: When user touch or click within one minute then set it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)** or **[CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)** for counting the time or schedule the next task. After the time finish you need to redirect to home screen.

- If the Home screen is just before the current screen simply call finish() or context.finish() to move the Home screen.
- If the Home screen is not just before the current screen use intent to reach the Home screen.

Hope it will helpful.